# Is there a way to convert z3 expressions like a & b & 1 into a & b?

Tags: python, boolean, z3

I am a beginner in z3. The requirement is to convert a & b & 1 into a & b. I tried using simplify(). But it gives the de-Morgan equivalent ~(~a | ~b).
(But if the expression has only one variable, eg: a & 1, then simplify gives 'a', as expected).
Is there a way to do this for multiple variables ??

Here is a snippet ::

```
from z3 import *

a=BitVec('a',1)
b=BitVec('b',1)
c=BitVec('c',1)
d=BitVec('d',1)


z = [a&1, b&c&1&d]
for term in z:
    z1=simplify(term)
    print(z1)
```

expected output:

```
a
b & c & d
```

output generated by the above code::

```
a
~(~b | ~c | ~d)
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide a snippet of sample code, outlining what you tried already? Ideally, this snippet is self-contained and can be run by anyone looking into your problem

Comment: Hey! Thanks for looking into the question :) 
I have added a  snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you use `Bool` instead of bit-vector:

```py
from z3 import *

a=Bool('a')
b=Bool('b')
c=Bool('c')
d=Bool('d')


z = [And(a,True), And(b,c,True,d)]
for term in z:
    z1=simplify(term)
    print(z1)
```

This prints:

```
a
And(b, c, d)
```

Note that if you use `BitVec` (instead of `Bool`) you are creating a bit-vector, not a boolean, and z3 treats those quite differently.

In general, trying to "force" the z3 simplifier to generate something that you'd consider *simple* is a futile attempt: The simplifier will indeed do a lot of simplifications, to make the problem simpler for further solving by the SAT/SMT engines. However, solver's notion of "simple" hardly matches what a human would consider simple, which generally means more "aesthetically pleasing" than anything else. This is not the goal of the z3 simplifier, whose sole job is to make sure the eventual formulas are easier to manipulate by the theory solvers.

Having said that, you can get detailed info on simplify parameters to see if you can use them in certain contexts. Try:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> help_simplify()
```

And it will dump a lot of options that you can pass to the simplify engine for various effects. But always keep in mind that none of these are designed for "readability," they're all about "easy-to-manipulate-later-on."